# Cargar script dinamicamente en angular

Tags: javascript, angular

estoy colocando un script que da la funcionalidad de chat en mi aplicación, si lo coloco dentro del index.html en la sección del header este es cargado de forma correcta y el chat funciona bien,
el problema es que debo mostrarlo de forma dinámica mediante un parámetro que decide si se muestra o no dentro de un componente, el script es como el siguiente

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _smartsupp = _smartsupp || {};
_smartsupp.key = 'XXX';
window.smartsupp||(function(d) {
  var s,c,o=smartsupp=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
  s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
  c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
  c.src='https://www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
})(document);
</script>
```

He intentado sacar el código JavaScript y colocarlo dentro de una función en el componente pero no funciona.

buscando encontre este codigo pero tampoco parece funcionar

```
 var loadJS = function(implementationCode, location){
        //url is URL of external file, implementationCode is the code
        //to be called from the file, location is the location to 
        //insert the <script> element
    
        var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    
        scriptTag.onload = implementationCode;
        scriptTag.onreadystatechange = implementationCode;
    
        location.appendChild(scriptTag);
    };
    var yourCodeToBeCalled = function(){
        var _smartsupp = _smartsupp || {};
    _smartsupp.key = 'XXX';
    window.smartsupp||(function(d) {
      var s,c,o=smartsupp=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
      s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
      c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
      c.src='https://www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
    })(document);
    }
    loadJS(yourCodeToBeCalled, document.body);
```

Comment: [Esta pregunta quizá te ayude.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398001/angular-10-javascript-personalizado-no-es-le%c3%addo-por-los-m%c3%b3dulos/399611?noredirect=1#comment715187_399611)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear un archivo independiente con tu script, ejemplo "cargarChat.js", que contendría el código que mencionas

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _smartsupp = _smartsupp || {};
    _smartsupp.key = 'XXX';
    window.smartsupp||(function(d) {
      var s,c,o=smartsupp=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
      s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
      c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
      c.src='https://www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
    })(document);
 </script>
```

Y en el componente que necesitas iniciarlo, puedes utilizar jquery para ponerlo en tu index asi:

```
$.getScript(nameScript, function (data, estado) {
      if (estado == 'success') {
        console.log("Cargado script");
      }
      else {
        alert("Error al cargar la librería autocomplete");
      }
    });
```

De esta manera el script se carga dinámicamente cuando lo necesites.

Answer (score 1):

El script crea un div con id `chat-application`. Puedes dejar el script en el index.html y desde los componentes modificar la visibilidad del div.

Si se quiere ocultar:

```
document.getElementById('chat-application').style.display = "none";
```

Si se quiere mostrar:

```
document.getElementById('chat-application').style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Gracias me diste la idea para solucionar el problema