# ¿Cómo usar un archivo JS con JQuery en Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Estoy intentando usar un archivo concreto escrito en JQuery, pero no me lo está pillando de ninguna forma. Uso Angular para desarrollar mi web, y tengo entendido que tienes que declarar el uso de ese archivo de forma "especial", he estado leyendo por internet respuestas de gente que ha tenido un problema similar, pero no me lo detecta bien.

Primero de todo instalé JQuery mediante el comando `npm install --save jquery @types/jquery`. Después lo declaré en el archivo `angular.json`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el propio index:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo esto teniendo el archivo en la carpeta de `assets`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Igual estoy obviando algo, pero no me doy cuenta de qué, llevo ya un buen rato intentando solucionarlo pero no se me ocurre nada ni encuentro nada más.

Estoy usando la versión 11 de Angular.

Comment: Pienso que revisar esta pregunta podría ayudarte a entender lo que pasa https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/398001/55132

Comment: Añadiendo al comentario de @Lobos, cabe mencionar que Angular trabaja con módulos y componentes **compilados**. Si bien los recursos se cargarán, a menos que explícitamente hagas componentes sin aislamiento y predefinas los respectivos bindings de tu archivo .js, los componentes no podrán interactuar con tu archivo. Si de todas formas necesitas usar jquery, usa los módulos en un componente de la aplicación. Puedes revisar la [documentación](https://angular.io/api/core/Component) para más información. Luego, según convenga, puedes aplicar el uso de [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)